# Import .csv file into Adobe AIR iOS App

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, air, adobe

I have created an Adobe AIR app where I can import a csv file and parse it into a sqlite db.  Great!  I use the browseForOpen() to search for the file.  I want to take this app and put it on an iOS device but cannot figure out how to search or import the csv file into the app.  Through email? Dropbox?  I need help.  Been searching for hours.  Would love some steps or even some example code.

Thanks!

Comment: None of the above. You just cannot do that on iOS, at least through AIR anyway (with regard to native file browsing). You'll need to either download the CSV file from a server or store it within the app itself (via embedding)

Comment: But...what if I just ask the user to copy the whole csv, paste it into a text box and parse it through there?  too messy of a user experience?

Comment: Very much so. The user should never be required to paste some data into your application. The application should always handle that on its own.

Comment: so there is no way to copy a csv into the applicationStorageDirctory...even without browse?  What about save an attachment from email into the app?   Then have the app see it and parse it from a list.  Really appreciate the help btw!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? You can save it to `applicationStorageDirectory`, of course you can. But where is it coming from? You **cannot** access *any* data from *any* other app. Period. You cannot save an attachment into your app. Just download the CSV file from a server and save it to disk. Why is that not an option?

Comment: We're talking class lists (students first names, last names, gender) from teachers that just need to get imported into a db for app usage.  The teachers would have to upload it to a secure server and access it on the app.  Seems like a lot of work for just a simple import, plus its something that is over my head at the moment.  These restrictions in iOS are terrible.